# how to send access token directly through browser

Tags: python, browser, get, jwt, flask-jwt

This is my fuction for accepting a HTTP GET request:

```
class Test2(Resource):
        @jwt_required
        def get(self):
            mailid = request.args.get('mailid', '')
            username = request.args.get('username', '')
            password = request.args.get('password', '')
            print("Mail ID, Username, Password = ")
            print(mailid, username, password)
            return 'Not supported'
```

I am getting the error "Missing Authorization Header" when I try the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/test2?mailid=ABC.xyz.com&username=ABC&password=password&jwt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTIzODc0MzAyLCJpYXQiOjE1MjM4NzM0MDIsImZyZXNoIjpmYWxzZSwibmJmIjoxNTIzODczNDAyLCJqdGkiOiI2NzYxNzdmNS05NGE3LTQzYTUtYjVhYy1mMmVlMzhhN2JhOWEiLCJpZGVudGl0eSI6MTIzfQ.iXZ9_qDtTw5_Q2VxEpvv5pYVAaI8M7P_CVy2Ln79eok
```

Comment: That error tells you that the API expects an Authorization header, probably something like "Authorizaion: bearer eyJ0e....". But you send the token as a request parameter. Better use Fiddler or Postman to test your API

Comment: Can you share the code for the jwt_required wrapper as well?

Comment: I cleaned up the text and reformatted the URL as code.

Comment: Hey @nitish albin, I see you accepted my answer and then reversed the accept - is there anything in particular you are looking for, or that I can help you with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using *requests*, then you can access the headers like so:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
# this is just an example from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/
headers = r.headers
```

here *headers* is a dict and has keys like *content-type*. Check the documentation for more info.

From your code it looks like the decorator *@jwt_required* checks the header for an auth field in the request header - you should look there. 
If you can edit the question and add the code, you could get more specific help.